# Can a foreign key be a primary key?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, erd

[image]

I want to know the relationship takes, teaches, advisors tables underlined attributes are foreign key or primary key? or both?

Comment: There are various graphical notations, CHEN, UML, IDEF1X to name a few. I suggest you find out what notation that is used, and look up what an underlined attribute means

Comment: Just tell me if a relation "abc" represent two entity sets and have many to many relations between them, then the common attributes/PK's from both table inside "abc" relations are pk or fk? or both?

Comment: Nothing prevents the column/expression to be both PK and FK. Common 1:1 relation.

Comment: So, if it is many to many then it is pk from both table and in that relation table it is fk and can be connected with each other many times right?